# Load images from a specific subdomain [cookieless domain]

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, cookies, subdomain, cdn

I want to load all the user images and CSS/JS from my subdomain where cookie is disabled. 
For Example the old code for CSS was **{{asset('css/style.css')}}**, How can automatically set the path to my **subdomain** and load the css from there.

I don't to manually find, edit and update every line of code.

Comment: Add your subdomain path in .env like SUB_DOMAIN = cccc.com. And use it while loading css like that env('SUB_DOMAIN' ).'/css/style.css''